# Can you create "global" methods to use in several fragments at once?

Tags: android, android-fragments, methods, global-variables

Sorry for the question, I'm sure there is, but I can't see how I could do it, I imagine creating a java file that saves the global methods and thus using them in the fragment that I require, if you can help me how to do it, and if you can give me an example it would be helpful

I have not tried anything, because I do not get something to talk about that, I want to try in all the fragments that I have if there is a connection and if there is not, that I close the application, and the code I have works fine, but it seems to me that I am grabbing something wrong by placing the same methods the all fragment

```
private void verificarconexion() {
    //para saber si hay internet

    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {

        if (networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
            // Estas conectado a un Wi-Fi

            Log.d("MIAPP", " Nombre red Wi-Fi: " + networkInfo.getExtraInfo());
        }

    } else {
        //Intent salida=new Intent( Intent.ACTION_MAIN); //Llamando a la activity principal
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "no tienes internet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mostrarsalir();

    }



}

private void mostrarsalir() {
    final CharSequence[] opciones={"Aceptar","Cancelar"};
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setTitle("No se detectan redes de internet");

    builder.setItems(opciones, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            if (opciones[i].equals("Aceptar")){
                getActivity().finish();
                System.exit(0);
                int p = android.os.Process.myPid();
                android.os.Process.killProcess(p);
            }else{
                getActivity().finish();
                System.exit(0);
                int p = android.os.Process.myPid();
                android.os.Process.killProcess(p);
            }

        }
    });
    builder.show();
}
```

I would like to write the method in a place where I can call it from any fragment, because if I want to change a letter of the message I show, I don't have to look in all the fragments where the method is

Comment: All questions and answers on the main Stack Overflow site are required to be in English. Please either translate your question or try [es.so].

Comment: The question is in English tho, it's only the code comment and variables that are spanish

Comment: The Activity could be a place for a method that all Fragments in that Activity will call.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use string resources to define string once in all project:
strings.xml:

```
<string name="DEFAULT">Default</string>
```

java code :

```
context.getString(R.string.DEFAULT)
```

and if you want to define the function once, simply define a class with static function like that :

```
 public class Helper{
    public static void function(){
        //code
    }
}
//call function
Helper.function();
```